# Repeated roots/solutions for a numerical solution

Tags: equation-solving, numerical-value

*Consider the equation,*

$x^2 + e^x + y^2 + y = 4, -2 \leq x \leq 2$

*Solve for $y$ numerically using **FindRoot***

My attempt:

```
f[y_, x_] := x^2 + y^2 + E^x + y  - 4
    
startvalues = Table[y /. Solve[f[y, i] == 0, y], {i, -2, 2, 0.5}]

Print[""]   
    
Table[FindRoot[f[y, j] == 0, {y, startvalues}], {j, -2, 2, 0.5}]}
```

Result:

[image]

As observed, there are repeated roots. How do I get rid of the repeated roots such that there's exactly one solution for each initial guess?
I have tried using a Do loop, but null values are generated

Comment: Why would you solve something that you already have solved? You already got solutions by using `Solve`, what is the point of using `FindRoot` to get the same solutions?

Comment: The question looks like homework, and that suggests to me a particular approach was taught and should be used. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f[y_, x_] := x^2 + y^2 + E^x + y - 4

xmax = NMaxValue[{x, f[y, x] == 0}, {x, y}, WorkingPrecision -> 20]

(* 1.1068629565922608666 *)
```

**EDIT:** Corrected test used in `DeleteDuplicates`

```
data = DeleteDuplicates[
   Flatten[
    Outer[{#1, y /. FindRoot[f[y, #1], {y, #2},
         WorkingPrecision -> 15]} &,
     Range[-2, xmax, (xmax + 2)/10], {1/2, -3/2}], 1],
   Norm[#1 - #2] < 10^-6 &];

ContourPlot[f[y, x] == 0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -3, 2},
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {x, y}),
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4], Point[data]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Very nicely done. Just a quick question: is the high value of `WorkingPrecision` related to the use of `FindRoot`?

Comment: @bmf - I tend to always use a `WorkingPrecision` when using `FindRoot`. The choice of `15` in the `FindRoot` is somewhat arbitrary. `20` was used in the `NMaxValue` to ensure the inputs to `FindRoot` were always consistent with its `WorkingPrecision` of `15`

Comment: Thanks for breaking it down :)

Answer (score 0):

```
f[y_, x_] := x^2 + y^2 + E^x + y - 4
startvalues = Table[{i, y /. Solve[f[y, i] == 0, y]}, {i, -2, 2, 0.5}]
FindRoot[f[y, #[[1]]] == 0, {y, #[[2, 1]]}] & /@ startvalues
FindRoot[f[y, #[[1]]] == 0, {y, #[[2, 2]]}] & /@ startvalues
Clear[startvalues, f]

(* {{-2.,{-0.838622,-0.161378}},{-1.5,{-1.83299,0.832993}},{-1.,{-2.19768,1.19768}},{-0.5,{-2.34214,1.34214}},{0.,{-2.30278,1.30278}},{0.5,{-2.03339,1.03339}},{1.,{-1.22919,0.22919}},{1.5,{-0.5-1.57534 I,-0.5+1.57534 I}},{2.,{-0.5-2.6719 I,-0.5+2.6719 I}}} *)
(* {{y->-0.838622},{y->-1.83299},{y->-2.19768},{y->-2.34214},{y->-2.30278},{y->-2.03339},{y->-1.22919},{y->-0.5-1.57534 I},{y->-0.5-2.6719 I}} *)
(* {{y->-0.161378},{y->0.832993},{y->1.19768},{y->1.34214},{y->1.30278},{y->1.03339},{y->0.22919},{y->-0.5+1.57534 I},{y->-0.5+2.6719 I}} *)
```